# ¿Cómo crear un campo auto-incrementable en Moongose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Mi pregunta es como crear un campo autoincrementable en una colección de *mongodb* con *moongose*.

A continuación les muestro el modelo que deseo agregar dentro un campo autoincrementable:

```
    import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const actividadSchema = new Schema({
    nombre: { type: String, maxlength: 200 },
    descripcion:{ type: String },
    estado: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    eliminar: { type: Number, default: 1 },
    createdAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    "campoAutoIncrementable"----> campo para agregar en la tabla
});

const Actividad = mongoose.model('actividad', actividadSchema);

export default Actividad;
```

Cualquier ayuda o consejo se agradece

Comment: Hola Jimmy, ¿qué has intentado por tu cuenta? Por otro lado, recuerda que Mongo es una BD noSQL, por lo cual no está pensada para hacer uso de campos autoincrementables. Esto no significa que no se pueda hacer. Pero es como tratar de ponerle cinturón de seguridad a una moto. O sea, no va con la moto, pero igual se le puede poner. ¿La utilidad? Pues eso lo determinas tú. Si requieres almacenar datos de forma relacional, tal vez usar Mongo no sea lo indicado. Saludos

Comment: muchas gracias por tu comentario Mauricio.

Comment: Jimmy, ¿aún no has dado con una solución? ¿Podrías aclarar un poco lo que has intentado? Saludos

Comment: Perdon la demora, ya lo pude soluccionar y subi la respuestas, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hay necesidad de que hagas todo ese codigo ya que MongoDB provee de un operador llamado **$inc**  que como su nombre lo indica incrementa un valor de tu colección

Por ejemplo:

Si quieres actualizar la cantidad de productos puedes hacer esto

```js
db.products.update({ _id: ObjectId("19222n282jws0") },{ $inc: { quantity: +1} })
```

Answer (score 2):

La soluccion que se me ocurrio y me ayudo a soluccionar el problema es la siguiente

en el modelo anterior antes comentado cree un campo llamado correlativo que fuera un Number

Crear una api que rescate la ultima actividad que se crea.

```
    ultimoNro:async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const reg = await models.Actividad.find(
      .sort({
        $natural:-1
      }).limit(1);
    res.status(200).json(reg);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Ocurrió un error"
    });
    next(e);
  }
},
```

Despues dentro de una aplicacion creo el siguiente metodo

```
listarNumeroVale() {
  let me = this;
  let header = {
    Token: this.$store.state.token
  };
  let configuracion = {
    headers: header
  };
  axios
    .get("actividad/ultimoNro", configuracion)
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      me.correlativo= response.data[0].correlativo;//rescato el valor que viene en documento JSON
      if (!me.correlativo) {//le indico si el valor es null le asigne un valor por defecto 1001
        me.correlativo= 1001;
      } else {//si no que traiga el valor anterior y el sume uno
        me.correlativo= me.nroVale + 1;
      }

      console.log("el ultimo numero de vales es: ", correlativo);
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
},
```

De esta manera lo almaceno en la variable y creo un auto-incrementable.

Gracias a la pagina y a todos los integrantes :)